# Using a Visual C++ project from other

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a Visual C++ 2008 express solution with 2 projects (A, B).
I want to use the files in project A in the project B but I have an error.
`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol [...]`

If I try to include a file of project A (a.hpp) in the project B, I have linker errors. If I include the cpp file too (a.cpp) these errors dissapear.

How can I avoid to include the .cpp files explicitly?

Comment: If the project you need generates a library, you should include it in the other project's dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it is necessary to add the "external" project to current project's references. Doing this, I have no errors. (I mean, right click on project > references > add new reference > select your project)

However, to include the files, it's necessary to add the root folder of the external project to "additional include directories" or add the complete path (absoulte o relative) to the include statement.

For example, in my case I have to do:

```
// From project B, mainB.cpp
#include ../A/a.h  // if "../A" is not in "additional include directories"
```